# CREDENTIALS MISSING when trying to submit oem13c library job from oem database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have an application that runs certain jobs in oem11g directly from the oem-database using the sysman.mgmt_jobs package and the submit_job_from_library procedure. After moving to oem13c, I tried to do a similar job launch using the sysman package.gc_job (as oracle advises in the package comments), a job is created, but with the credentials missing error. I don't know what else to try :(

I looked through all the procedures, compared jobs that work without errors with my own. I checked the MGMT_CREDENTIALS2_E table, tried to run it directly through the sysman.em_job_ops package. I did not find any information about the use of these packages

Comment: You have not asked a question nor given a [MRE] that would allow us to replicate any problem that you may have a question about. Please [edit] your post to ask a question and include the appropriate code so we can replicate the problem.